# Creating jhipster - MongoDb getting an error

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jhipster

I have created new project with jhipster with MongoDB and get this error below Also I tried running the project in ec2 server and  get the same error the problem is :

```
class  com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings
```

found in two directly

```
jar:file:/home/ali/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.0.4/b7fab8d7def083e8e33660995a4c34855eebdd60/mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class
    jar:file:/home/ali/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.11.2/dcf3f0110aecf1ea9f55c1f12e2b6b68d3c48322/mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class
```

in gradle file I use

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive"
```

this is the stack trace
....

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
    com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster(DefaultClusterFactory.java:182)
The following method did not exist:
    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;
The method's class, com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings, is available from the following locations:
    jar:file:/home/ali/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.0.4/b7fab8d7def083e8e33660995a4c34855eebdd60/mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class
    jar:file:/home/ali/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.11.2/dcf3f0110aecf1ea9f55c1f12e2b6b68d3c48322/mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class
The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings: file:/home/ali/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.0.4/b7fab8d7def083e8e33660995a4c34855eebdd60/mongodb-driver-core-4.0.4.jar
Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the used jhipster version and configuration. I am unable to reproduce it with the latest master branch, the application starts just fine.